# Execute scheduled cron with ajax call to wp-cron.php

Tags: php, wp-cron, cron

According to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/419379/wp-mail-send-emails-after-24-hours-from-users-registration) where my doubt on how to schedule an email sending each 24 hours, I've modified my plugin code to use a custom action hook and the `wp_schedule_single_event()` to achive the scope. I've readed about WordPress cron and about the function and I've discovered that the events will be executed only when the website have traffic. Since the hosting provider don't give me the ability to schedule cron, I've created a simple nodejs script that will call the website using the `https.get` function. According to the WordPress documentation I've readed that I can also call directly the `wp-cron.php` to run the scheduled tasks. My qyestion is, if I use the node script, I can call directly the php script that will run the cron or there is some security measure in wp-cron.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wp-cron.php is not secured. It can be called from anywhere and by anyone.

Comment: Yes. that's what [the instructions on WordPress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/) say to do.

Comment: Do I need to do a post or a get request?

Comment: A get request works.